# Use multiple AntiVirus engine

Tags: antivirus

I’ve found some codes and AntiViruses which use multiple Antivirus’s engines in their products. Like https://github.com/joxeankoret/multiav and some other code or products.

How?

and
What about License?

Answer (score 2):

There is typically no reason for programs not to interact when the programs offer some sort of API - in the case of the linked product, it answers your

> how?

In the readme:

> It uses, with the only exception of ClamAV, the command line AV
>   scanners and extracts the malware names from the output of the command
>   line tools (for ClamAV it uses the https://code.google.com/p/pyclamd/
>   extension).

As you asked for an actual example: let’s say a anti virus solution has a CLI that works like this:

`av file` returns either `ok` or `bad`.

A program can now call `av file`, for example via a `system` call and read the output of that CLI, then decide with a string matching on `ok` or `bad` to decide what to present to the user for this particular file for this anti virus.

This can be repeated for as much CLIs as supported.

As to the licensing: of course the supported AV solutions must be present and functional on the machine, leaving this to the user.

In an attempt to make this on-topic, I will highlight why it is useful to use different AV products on files.

As some examples on virus total show, individual anti virus solutions have vastly different results in identifying malicious files.

This for example comes from:

- different paces and update cycles of different vendors due to different office hours and analysis priorities
- different approaches to heuristics and sandboxing.
- different niches, one might find windows malware, one might find Mac malware.

Comment: Thanks but not clear enough for me. Can you give me an example to show how? You must install multiple AVs in your single system. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to install multiple AV solutions side by side. As to an example: that depends on the programming language and specific products and their command line tools. That would be off topic here and probably too basic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think it is not off topic. Because I`ve asked how. I really appreciate you if you update your answer and explain this question.

Comment: Mohammad, that question would definitely be off topic here.

Comment: The answer to whether or not you _must_ intall multiple AVs? No. Typically installing more does not help much, and might even increase the chance that malware exploits a vulnerability in your AV to gain higher privileges.

Comment: If not, How aforementioned softwares and codes use multiple AV engines? I mean, according to your example, it is really need to install the AV to use its CLI. Correct?

Comment: A big professional service may use other methods to hook into purely graphical AVs. They may also be using some business solution where the AV exposes an API. Note also that all these AVs are not running together, but typically on separate virtual machines. Running multiple AVs together can be a recipe for disaster, as they may begin to attack each other.

Comment: @guest while that is definitely true and it has positive sites to have a Solution to have an array of VMs for detection, the linked product has them installed next to each other and called on a CLI - this BTW does not mean they have to run next to each other. They just need to be installed and working.